# Why can memory leaking by cross-reference be solved by explicit reassignment in Perl?

Tags: perl

Cross-reference causes memory leaking in Perl like this.

```perl
{
    my @a = qw(a b c);
    my @b = qw(a b c);
    # both reference count are 1
    push @a, \@b;
    # @b reference count is 2(from @b and via @a)
    push @b, \@a;
}
# @b reference count is 2(from via @a)
```

I understand memory leaking by cross-reference in this situation.
But the memory leaking can be resolve by explicit reassignment like this.

```
{
    my @a = qw(a b c);
    my @b = qw(a b c);
    # both reference count are 1
    push @a, \@b;
    # @b reference count is 2(from @b and via @a)
    push @b, \@a;
    @a = ();
}
# why is @b reference count 0?
```

@a is lexical scope so I think even if there is no reassignment, @a's reference will be invalid but former cause memory leaking and later is not, why?

Comment: There's no such thing as an invalid reference

Comment: @ikegami : Having fought some wars against: "Error in `perl': double free or corruption (!prev): 0x000...."  I tend to disagree ;-)

Comment: @Georg Mavridis, Sounds like buggy C code to me, not buggy Perl code.

Comment: Yes, one issue was a buggy perl 5.16.3 No additional C code included, but as "select isn't broken" it takes some time to realize that.

Answer (score 5):

You start with

```
@a                  @b
|   ARRAY           |   ARRAY
|   REFCNT=2        |   REFCNT=2
+-->+-----------+   +-->+-----------+
|   | +-------+ |   |   | +-------+ |
|   | | a     | |   |   | | a     | |
|   | +-------+ |   |   | +-------+ |
|   | | b     | |   |   | | b     | |
|   | +-------+ |   |   | +-------+ |
|   | | c     | |   |   | | c     | |
|   | +-------+ |   |   | +-------+ |
|   | |     --------+   | |     --------+
|   | +-------+ |       | +-------+ |   |
|   +-----------+       +-----------+   |
|                                       |
+---------------------------------------+
```

If you were to exit the scope here, the reference counts would drop to one, and they would leak.

After `@a = ();`:

```
@a                  @b
|   ARRAY           |   ARRAY
|   REFCNT=2        |   REFCNT=1
+-->+-----------+   +-->+-----------+
|   |           |       | +-------+ |
|   |           |       | | a     | |
|   |           |       | +-------+ |
|   |           |       | | b     | |
|   |           |       | +-------+ |
|   |           |       | | c     | |
|   |           |       | +-------+ |
|   |           |       | |     --------+
|   |           |       | +-------+ |   |
|   +-----------+       +-----------+   |
|                                       |
+---------------------------------------+
```

Note that `@b`'s reference count went from two to one.

On scope exit, `@a`'s reference count will drop to one, and `@b`'s reference count will drop to zero.<sup>[1]</sup> This will free `@b`, which will cause `@a`'s reference count to drop to zero. And that will free `@a`.

No cycle, so no memory leak.

---

1. At least in theory. In practice, what actually happens is a bit different as an optimization. But those are internal details that aren't relevant here.

Comment: Thank you. I didn't know that reinitialize don't effect to reference in Perl.

Comment: Changing the contents of your house doesn't change your street address. Same idea here.

Comment: Note that `$a=[]; $b=[]; $b[0]=$a; $a[0]=$b; $a=undef;` would be different. `$a=undef;` would not change the contents of `@$a`, and thus wouldn't break the cycle, and thus wouldn't prevent the memory leak. I believe this is what you were thinking of.